# Specify a Group of PHPUnit Tests to Run in Seperate Processes

Tags: php, annotations, phpunit

In PHPUnit, you can annotate a test-case class (`@runTestsInSeparateProcesses`) or a test function (`@runInSeparateProcess`) to run tests in process isolation. There is also a setting in the `phpunit.xml` config file (`processIsolation = "true"`) to run all tests in separate processes.

I have a group of test-case classes which all inherit from a database-related abstract test class that I need to run in process isolation. But annotations aren't inherited from parent classes. Is there a way for me to mark these test-case classes to run in separate processes by @group, or directory, or some other specifier, without having to mark each test-case class with `@runTestsInSeparateProcesses`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is currently not possible. Feel free to open a feature request.